# Can't centre a table within a div in HTML and CSS - responsive website

Tags: html, css, center, centering

I'm trying to center an HTML table in CSS but the code is not working. I have tried justify-content, align-content, margins, etc but can't seem to get anything to work. The website needs to be responsive so all values need to be percentages (which makes it a bit harder). Additionally, for some reason, some of the columns are different widths to the last one?? Not sure about that either. I'll put the code below.

```css
.numberButton {
  background-color: #707070;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35%;
  text-align: center;
}

.tdNumber {
  width: 30%;
  height: 40%;
}

#numberTable {
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

#numberBackground {
  background-color: #3968CB;
  margin: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: 400%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body id="numberBackground">
  <div id="numberTable">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="one" class="numberButton">1</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="two" class="numberButton">2</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="three" class="numberButton">3</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="four" class="numberButton">4</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="five" class="numberButton">5</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="six" class="numberButton">6</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="seven" class="numberButton">7</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="eight" class="numberButton">8</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="nine" class="numberButton">9</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="ten" class="numberButton">10</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="eleven" class="numberButton">11</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="twelve" class="numberButton">12</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="thirteen" class="numberButton">13</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="fourteen" class="numberButton">14</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="fifteen" class="numberButton">15</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="sixteen" class="numberButton">16</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="seventeen" class="numberButton">17</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="eighteen" class="numberButton">18</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="nineteen" class="numberButton">19</button></td>
          <td class="tdNumber"><button id="twenty" class="numberButton">20</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button onclick="location.href='Topics Page.html'" type="button" id="backanimal" class="numberButton">BACK</button></td>
          <td><button onclick="location.href='Numbers_Test.html'" type="button" id="testanimal" class="numberButton">TEST</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you add ’display: flex;’ to the #numberTable css it should work with justify-content: center;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add position absolute to your table. Then use transform to position it at center.

```css
.numberButton {
  background-color: #707070;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35%;
  text-align: center;
}

.tdNumber {
  width: 30%;
  height: 40%;
}

#numberTable {
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#numberBackground {
  background-color: #3968CB;
  margin: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: 400%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="numberTable">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="one" class="numberButton">1</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="two" class="numberButton">2</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="three" class="numberButton">3</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="four" class="numberButton">4</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="five" class="numberButton">5</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="six" class="numberButton">6</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="seven" class="numberButton">7</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="eight" class="numberButton">8</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="nine" class="numberButton">9</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="ten" class="numberButton">10</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="eleven" class="numberButton">11</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="twelve" class="numberButton">12</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="thirteen" class="numberButton">13</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="fourteen" class="numberButton">14</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="fifteen" class="numberButton">15</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="sixteen" class="numberButton">16</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="seventeen" class="numberButton">17</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="eighteen" class="numberButton">18</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="nineteen" class="numberButton">19</button></td>
        <td class="tdNumber"><button id="twenty" class="numberButton">20</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button onclick="location.href='Topics Page.html'" type="button" id="backanimal" class="numberButton">BACK</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="location.href='Numbers_Test.html'" type="button" id="testanimal" class="numberButton">TEST</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: flex is sooo better

Comment: Thank you this works well; however, I also need to vertically expand the rows so that the table fills about 90% of the page. I have tried apply flexbox, but unsuccessfully (I am not very experienced in coding). Would you be able to help with this as well?

Comment: Do you want width and height to fill most of the page?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/hy163zj0/

Comment: Yes I have successfully done width but height doesn't seem to respond to changing measurements... I have tried the link and while it makes the first row much taller to fill the whole page it doesn't affect the other rows.

Comment: But it is strange because your code works in fiddle. I am using Adobe Dreamweaver - not sure if this would make any difference? Previewing in chrome.

Comment: Remove the style for tdNumber and try again

Comment: Wow that's amazing thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you want Use  **align-items: center;** and **justify-content: center;** first must use **display: flex** and ..., I fix your code but you must more organize that.

```
#numberTable {
display: flex;
align-items: center; 
justify-content: center;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.tdNumber{
height: auto;
padding: .2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add below mentioned CSS codes in your  numberBackground tag, your problem will be solved. For inside box elements sizes you can use flex-child properties.

```
#numberBackground {
background-color: #3968CB;
margin: 0px;
width: auto;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
/* justify-content: center; */
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :) Please consider reformatting code and enable syntax highlighting that makes it easier to read :)